# Add a "landfill" tag to the sites tags (withdrawn)

Tags: discussion, support

A user recently suggested in a comment that we have a "landfill" tag:

> I just think we also need to explicitly label unreliable sites as unreliable/conspiracy/etc. instead of letting people assume a specific article in question is an outlier for the site. Going off your garbage metaphor, instead of picking up one piece of trash at a time, we can add the "landfill" tag to sites that earn it. That's all I was doing. Suggesting that we should do it everywhere we can on this Stack goes beyond my original comment, but what I think we should do.

I agree that this is a good suggestion. We have several questions where the person asking the question obviously does not think that what was written / said in the properly cited notable claim is true and is asking for help in debunking said claim.

The downside is yet another question that says "NASA claims it landed people on the Moon. No Way!" and marks the question as "landfill". The solution to those questions is simple: Drop them in the closed question landfill.

I suspect that if we do add a "landfill" it will mostly help avoid some of the downvotes, mostly made by newbies who do not quite understand the site, who do not like the question. It is questions about these disgusting but notable claims that are most in need of a solid dose of skepticism.

Edit: Request withdrawn, given the comment by staff member V2Blast. It seemed like a good idea at the time.

Comment: I'm the user that suggested it, and my use of "tag" is a generic one, not specific to SE/SO tags. I was thinking that it could be (highly) suggested to answerers (but not a requirement) to include a bit of background information on the source(s) cited by the question, as to how reliable the source is. I also wrote a question some time back about Media Bias Fact Check to be used as a reliable way to check the reliability of sites: [Is Media Bias Fact Check a reliable site?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4589/is-media-bias-fact-check-a-reliable-site)

Comment: Related: [Some basic skepticism tips when reading the news, and applying this to answers](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4763/some-basic-skepticism-tips-when-reading-the-news-and-applying-this-to-answers)

Comment: Related: [Should we close question about claims taken from reputable peer-reviewed publications?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4366/should-we-close-question-about-claims-taken-from-reputable-peer-reviewed-publica)

Comment: When making tags isn't one of the goals to be able to find people who could be experts in the tag? Would that be possible for a tag like this?

Comment: This seems like it'd be a ["meta tag"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) (i.e. not describing the content of the question, but rather "some other aspect of the question, like the author’s skill level, or the author’s motivation for asking it, or generally what 'kind' of question it is"). As such, it'd be an inappropriate use of a tag.

Comment: @V2Blast Request withdrawn.

Answer (score 5):

Given that "meta tags" are deemed verboten (and this definitely is asking for a "meta tag"), I'm withdrawing this request. If a user writes a question where they are questioning the validity of some notable claim, it's probably best to make that clear in the question.